# DEA analysis: variables are excluded in analysis?

Tags: r

I’m working on a DEA (Data Envelopment Analysis) analysis to analyze the relative effects of different banks efficiencies.

The packages I’m using are rDEA and kableExtra.

What this analysis if doing is measuring the relative effect of input and output variables that I use to examine the efficiency for each individual bank.

The problem is that my code only includes two out of four output variables and I can’t find anywhere in the code where I ask it to do so.

Can some of you identify the problem?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried to format the data in several different ways, assign the created "inp_var" and "out_var" as a matrix'.

```
#install.packages('rDEA') 
#install.packages('dplyr')
#install.packages('kableExtra')

library(kableExtra)
library(rDEA)
library(dplyr)

dea <- tbl_df(PANELDATA)
head(dea)

inp_var <- select(dea, 'IE', 'NIE')
out_var <- select(dea, 'L', 'D', 'II','NII')
inp_var <- as.matrix(inp_var)
out_var <- as.matrix(out_var)


model <- dea(XREF= inp_var, YREF = out_var, X = inp_var, Y = out_var, model= "output", RTS = "constant")

model
```

I want a number between 0 and 1 for every observation, where the most efficient one receives a 1. What I get now is the same result no matter if I include the two extra output variables L and II or not.

L stands for Loans to the public and II for interest income and it would be weird if these variables had NO effect for the efficiency of banks.

Comment: Hi @Jessica. Could you please provide some piece of data to run your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could type this:

```
result <- cbind(round(model$thetaOpt, 3), round(model$lambda, 3))
rownames(result)<-dea[[1]]
colnames(result)<-c("Efficiency", rownames(result))
kable(result[,])
```

Comment: Hi WalMac, and welcome to StackOverflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.